# migrating mysql data with month name to a new structure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `monthly1` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `stat_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `january` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `february` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `march` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `april` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `may` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `june` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `july` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `august` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `september` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `october` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `november` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `december` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

Hi i have an existing mysql data with structure like above and i would like to migrate the data to a new structure like in the structure below

```
CREATE TABLE `monthly2` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `year` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `stat_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monthName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `monthlydata` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

how do i properly create the insert query to do this..i tried the query below but how do i set the monthName to be month name (january) instead of january data ?

```
INSERT INTO `monthly2` (`year`, `stat_id`, `cat_id`, `monthName`, `monthlydata`)
select `year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, `january`, `january`
from `monthly1 WHERE year >= '2010' AND year < '2018'
```

Comment: Use single quote instead of backtick.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: I'm not sure that storing the name of the month is the smartest idea ever.

Comment: And I thought that no one uses MyISAM anymore. !?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make the year column int in table monthly1.

Use the following query to insert records in another table:-

```
INSERT INTO 
monthly2  
(SELECT `id`,`year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, 'january', `january` FROM monthly1 
WHERE year >= 2010 AND year < 2018);
```

FYI

I have to remove the:-

```
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

for the test.

Comment: i tried it like this but i got duplicate entry.... INSERT INTO 
monthly2  
(SELECT `id`,`year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, 'january', `january` FROM monthly1 
WHERE year >= 2010 AND year < 2018);                                                       
 INSERT INTO 
monthly2  
(SELECT `id`,`year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, 'february', `February` FROM monthly1 
WHERE year >= 2010 AND year < 2018);   how do i do it it full year from january to december ?

Comment: remove id from monthly1 select

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Try

INSERT INTO 
monthly2  
(SELECT '',`year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, 'january', `january` FROM monthly1 
WHERE year >= 2010 AND year < 2018);

Comment: Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
INSERT INTO 
monthly2  
(SELECT '',`year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, 'january', `january` FROM monthly1 
WHERE year >= 2010 AND year < 2018);
```

Comment: Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Comment: INSERT INTO monthly2 (`year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`,`monthName`,`monthlydata`) SELECT `year`,`stat_id`,`cat_id`, 'january', `january` FROM monthly1 
WHERE year >= 2010 AND year < 2018;